# Button appears in UITableView cell after scrolling

Tags: uitableview

I'm not sure what's wrong with this code, but in a cell where I didn't add a button (I have a if that checks if I need to add it or not) the button appears after scrolling down and then scrolling up again.

This is the code for the cell generation function in the tableview.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CLASSshopCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"shopCell"];

    SKProduct * product = (SKProduct *) _products[indexPath.row];
    cell.titleCell.text = product.localizedTitle;
    cell.descCell.text  = product.localizedDescription;

    [_priceFormatter setLocale:product.priceLocale];
    cell.priceCell.text = [_priceFormatter stringFromNumber:product.price];


    // already yours, so no cart button
    if ([[CLASSIAPHelper sharedInstance] productPurchased:product.productIdentifier]) {
        cell.priceCell.text = @"Already yours";
    } else {
          UIButton *buyButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
          UIImage *btn = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cart.png"];
          UIImage *btnh = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cartHover.png"];

          [buyButton setBackgroundImage:btn forState:UIControlStateNormal];
          [buyButton setBackgroundImage:btnh forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
           buyButton.frame = CGRectMake(cell.bounds.size.width - 40,40, 24, 24);
           buyButton.tag = indexPath.row;

        [buyButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buyButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
         [cell.contentView addSubview:buyButton];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Logging some stuff I didn't notice nothing special, condition is always verified. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by myself using part of the code of another question.
Basically I'm now looping into the cell, clearing all the buttons before doing the test again.

```
for (UIView *subview in [self.contentView subviews]) 
{
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) 
    {
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The cell you added a button to will eventually be reused. That's why you'll have the button on the wrong cells ;)

As a solution, you should use different reuse identifiers for cells with and without the button.